# Spring SAML Okta - How to redirect to a custom URL in IDP initiated flow

Tags: saml, spring-saml, okta

My application's entry point is a custom URL , how do I tell Spring to redirect to my URL after a successful SAML dance ? I am using IDP initiated flow.

In my app. I have several versions defined depending on a client.

e.g Client abc goes to https:\localhost:8443\abc\admin and client xyz goes to https:\localhost:8443\xyz\admin

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a handler called SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler which redirects to an endpoint defined in "Default Relay State"  configuration item in Okta (application configuration).

So first thing go to Okta and specify a redirect URL in "Default Relay State"  property.  Then add this property to SAMLProcessingFilter  :

```
 samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler());
```

and once Spring-SAML authenticates successfully it'll redirect to your relay URL.